# IE Cursor changing in dropdown list

Tags: vb.net, razor

I have a drop down list and when you go through the items the cursor changes to the object behind it. I've looked online and found that this is an IE only issue with the Z-order. I've tried using a span block behind the options to trick it that I found on another form but no luck. Any suggestions?

razor vbhtml

```
<div class="col-110px" id="ItemContainer">
    <label class="select-label" for="Item">Item</label>
    <span>@Html.DropDownListFor(Function(m) m.Item, CType(Model.ItemList, IEnumerable(Of SelectListItem)), New With {.class = ""})</span><span></span>
</div>
span {
    position:relative;
    z-index:0;
}
span span {
    display:none;
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    height:100px;
    background:rgba(255, 0, 0, .25);
    z-index:-1;
}
span select:focus + span {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you will need to post your code.

Comment: Please edit your question instead and include the code there. It's very hard to read from the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I meant to post this earlier but I finally got it working ... mostly. If anyone has a better suggestion please let me know

In the future I want to clean this up to check if there is already a scroll bar present and abit more flexible

in your JS file add the following

```
function IEDropdownSpan() {
    //Add span behind drop downs to prevent cursor from changing. IE only
    //only run if IE or Edge 20+ as it will break in all other browsers
    var isIE = false || !!document.documentMode;
    var isEdge = !isIE && !!window.StyleMedia;

    if (isIE || isEdge) {
        $("select").each(function () {
            var $curSelect = $(this);
            var $parent = $curSelect.parent();
            var oldOverflowValue = "";

            //This if statement is due to several types of drop downs that do not fit the normal profile
            if (!($curSelect.parent('span').hasClass('iedropdownspan')) && !$curSelect.is('[class^=chosen]') && !$parent.parent().is('[class^=modal-content]')) {

                if ($curSelect.parent('span').length === 0) {
                    $curSelect.wrapAll("<span></span>");
                    $parent = $curSelect.parent();
                }

                if ($curSelect.next("<span></span>".length === 0)) {
                    $("<span></span>").insertAfter($curSelect);
                }

                $curSelect.focus(function () {

                    //You can add any conditions here. I had to remove the rest due to company privacy. But this is the level that the overflow has to be hidden on
                    if ($parent.closest("article .content")) {
                        oldOverflowValue = $parent.closest('article .content').css('overflow-y');
                        $parent.closest('article .content').css('overflow-y', 'hidden');
                    }

                    if (!$curSelect.parent('span').hasClass('iedropdownspan')) {
                        $parent.addClass('iedropdownspan');
                    }

                });
                $curSelect.blur(function () {
                    if ($parent.closest("article .content")) {
                        $('article .content').css('overflow-y', oldOverflowValue);
                    }

                    $parent.removeClass('iedropdownspan');
                    oldOverflowValue = "";
                });

            }


        });
    }
}
```